# CDI imports cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, cdi

i have written an application on my pc using CDI as the backing bean for jsf, the application works completely fine.

Now i setup everything on a new pc, installed glassfish 4.1, setup eclipse kepler by putting the installed jre as jdk7 from the glassfish folder.

when i make a war for the application on my pc and deploy it onto the glassfish server on the other pc everything works fine.

now i tried taking the project from my pc and imported it onto the new pc. the eclipse on the new pc wont recognize `import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;` giving compiler error that this annotation is not available.

> The import javax.enterprise.context cannot be resolved

it doesnt recognize **`javax.enterprise.context.*`** at all. like CDI is not available. i am using JDK 7 which contains JSR 346, so i am completely confused what the issue could be.

if i deploy the application directly through the glassfish admin console using the war file it works perfectly fine but if i try to publish it through eclipse, it gives me unresolved compilation errors

[image]

Comment: Sounds weird. Please add the exception stacktrace to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse did not import ALL glassfish jars, so you need to:
Right Click on the project name, Build Path, Configure build path, under Libraries Click Add External Jars, go to where you have extracted Glassfish and import all jars that exists in:
glassfish4\glassfish\modules
and all sub directories two, like endoresed.

This will fix the problem for CDI and other stuff lik JAX-RS

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, your `.project` and `.classpath` files are pointing to JAR locations that are specific to your old computer.

This is why people like build tools such as maven, or gradle, you can pick up and reimport a project; it'll resolve all dependencies for you.

Comment: is maven my only option to solve this issue, is it not possible to do this without build tools. i only ask because i have no experience using any of them

Comment: You can click on "Fix project setup..." and it will do the work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to use the GlassFish Tools plugin for Eclipse? I found that the `GlassFish System Libraries` classpath container, which is created implicitly by that plugin and which is added to all projects that specify a GlassFish server as their runtime, misses `cdi-api.jar`. This is where the `javax.enterprise.context.*` package is located (and many others).

So I could fix this by adding `cdi-api.jar` as an External Jar to the build path. After that, you may get a warning like `Classpath entry [...]/cdi-api.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.`, which can be eliminated by using the Quick Fix to `Exclude the associated raw classpath entry from the set of potential publish/export dependencies`. That JAR file is already contained in the modules folder of GlassFish, obviously.

Maybe this problem only occurs with the GlassFish Web Profile, at least that's what I use.